# How to display data inside the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, kendo-ui

This is my current code, the problem is I dont know how to return the value, i dont know why the author from my function are undefined, what i want is to get the data from my query and pass it to the `const reportChart`, please help, thanks

this is my full code? did i miss something?

```
<script>
    async function myFunction() {
       var author = ("SELECT name FROM People", 10, (value)=>{
              console.log(value)//please see the data below
              return value;
        })
      return author; //undefined
    }
    myFunction().then(function(value){reportChart(value);})
    const reportChart = (value) => {
      console.log("inside chart: ",value) //The value of value is undefined
         $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "School Library"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: false
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "bar"
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: [1, 2, 3]
            }, {
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: [1, 2, 3]
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                max: 10,
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                minorGridLines: {
                    visible: true
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            },
             categoryAxis: {
                categories: [value],//undefined
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                }
              }, 
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
       
    }

    $(document).ready(reportChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", reportChart);
</script>
```

the result of **console.log(value)**

> 0: ['Mark'] 1: ['Joseph'] 2: ['Luna'] 3: ['Yuno']

**Update**

I remove some code and replace this

```
<script>
   let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject){
      var author = ("SELECT name FROM People", 10, (value) => {
         return myResolve(value)
       });
   })
   myPromise.then(
    function(value) {reportChart(value);},
    function(error) {reportChart(error);}
  );
    function reportChart (value, index) {
      console.log(index, value.length)
      var i = 0
      var author= []
      for(i=0; i<=value.length; i++)
        {
          author[i] = value[i]
        }
         $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Library"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: false
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "bar"
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: [1,2,3,4]
            }, {
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: [4,5,6,7]
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                max: 10,
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                minorGridLines: {
                    visible: true
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            },
             categoryAxis: {
                categories: [author],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                }
              }, 
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
       
    }
    $(document).ready(reportChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", reportChart);
</script>
```

**

this is now the result

[image]

What I want is, please help

[image]

Comment: The line `var author = ("SELECT name FROM People", 10, (value)=>{` is not working. It looks like it's meant to be part of a function call, and the `(value)=>{` is to be run on each returned value of the query. Also, does `console.log(value)` result in a single returned line containing all four results as you stated or four separate `console.log` entries?

Comment: hi @phentnil can you please help me on this one please?

Comment: `result in a single returned line containing all four results as you stated or four separate console.log entries?` yes

Comment: So, it's in one single line?

Comment: This is the exact result of `console.log(value)` = `0: ['Mark'] 1: ['Joseph'] 2: ['Luna'] 3: ['Yuno']`

Comment: (4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]

Comment: Okay, so it's a 2D array. So, accessing `Mark` would be done with `value[0][0]`, `Joseph` with `value[0][1]`, `Luna` with `value[0][2]`, and `Yuno` with `value[0][3]`. Do you want to return each author name separately or pass the array of author names to the `then` function?

Comment: this `pass the array of author names to the then function` yes

Comment: Is this the full code? The issue is not really [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with this code. Try placing `console.log` statements in the `then` function or other relevant places in your code.

Comment: that is my full code

Comment: i've tried this ` myFunction().then(function(value){reportChart(value); console.log("function: ",value)})` and the result are undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243337/discussion-between-kaito-and-phentnil).

Answer (score 0):

Here: `listsOfPeople = value`, I guess what you would like to to is `listsOfPeople.push(value);` instead?

---

Your code should be like `var author = doQuery("SELECT name FROM People"....`

Possible issues:

- `doQuery()` changes `listsOfPeople` unexpectedly.
- Just some typo mistake on your variable name.
- Or you mixed the use of `listsOfPeople` and `listsOfAuthor`.

Comment: wait let me try this

Comment: the value i get from`listsOfPeople` are `[]`

Comment: ```
var author = ("SELECT name FROM People", 10, (value)=>{
             console.log(value) //please see the results below
             listsOfPeople = value
        })
```
is not valid JavaScript. Have you missed to post some details inside it?

Comment: no, thats all in my code

Comment: maybe it will work on ajax, but the problem is I dont know how :(

Comment: Between `var author` and your SQL, there must be something to run the query, right?

Comment: @Sui Pang Tommy Choi , yes

Comment: So it should be like `var author = doQuery("SELECT name FROM People"...`. It could be the function `doQuery()` changes `listsOfPeople` unexpectedly. Or just some typo mistake on your variable name. Or you mixed the use of `listsOfPeople` and `listsOfAuthor`.

Comment: can you update your answer please?

Comment: please see my updated question, thanks